# css animation prefix errors

Tags: html, css, animation

I have a keyframes animation that works in chrome, but not in IE or Firefox.

I have tried using the -moz-animation prefix with @-moz-keyframes prefix, with one and not the other, and tried using neither, all the while including the standard non prefixed statements at the end of each css line.

However, no luck at all. Is there an error somewhere else in the code? I am using up to date browser verions.

HTML

```
   <div class="runner"></div>
```

CSS

```
    .runner {
        border-radius: 40pt ; 
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10pt grey ; 
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10pt grey ;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10pt grey ; 
        width:494px ; 
        height: 415.8px ; 
        position: absolute ; top:0 ; left: 0 ; 
        background: url(img/pic1.png) ;
       -webkit-animation: slideshow 20s infinite 2s ; animation: slideshow 20s infinite 2s
    }

    @-moz-keyframes slideshow {
    20% {background:url(pic1.png)}
    25%, 45% {background:url(img/pic2.png)}
    50%, 70% {background:url(img/pic3.png)}
    75%, 95% {background:url(img/pic4.png)}
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes slideshow {
    20% {background:url(img/pic1.png)}
    25%, 45% {background:url(img/pic2.png)}
    50%, 70% {background:url(img/pic3.png)}
    75%, 95% {background:url(img/pic4.png)}
    }

    @keyframes slideshow {
    20% {background:url(img/pic1.png)}
    25%, 45% {background:url(img/pic2.png)}
    50%, 70% {background:url(img/pic3.png)}
    75%, 95% {background:url(img/pic4.png)}
    }
```

Comment: You forgot to initiate animation for FF:

-webkit-animation: slideshow 20s infinite 2s;
animation: slideshow 20s infinite 2s;

There should be also -moz-animation there. :)

Comment: thanks but those as far as i understand the animation prefix is not needed anymore. anyway, adding it doesn't make any difference, it still doesn't run!

Comment: Works for me in FF and Chrome, take a look: http://jsfiddle.net/J9aer/ and another example with images: http://jsfiddle.net/J9aer/3/

Comment: take out the -webkit keyframes and it doesn't run in the fiddle

Comment: my apologies, it does run i ff jsfiddle, so then what could be the reason it refuses to run in the actual browser - well, for me anyway

Answer (score 1):

have you use `-moz-animation` in your `css`. I think that is not in your `css`, and for IE it works in IE 10.

Comment: you don't need that prefix anymore, but i've tried adding it anyway, still doesn't work!

Comment: your code is worked in my firefox 26.0. i have copied your code and try it, it works fine...

Comment: but it still doesn't work in mine - what could be the reason?